# Converting datastamps to epoch (including GMT or UTC)

Tags: java, parsing, timestamp

I am looking to convert timestamps into epoch (number of millisconds since 1970) - java.

I want an extensive parser - that supports both GMT/UTC and perheps other format.
For example:

```
new DateStamp("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,ccc o").parse("2012-09-01 13:44:21222 GMT+2")
```

That is, I don't want to put in the actual format my self (GMT/UTC), but rather leave that for the parser.

Comment: the kind I am looking for. There is no such class that I know off. O was just describing a desired form of use.

Comment: you should be able to parse the date (including time zone) with java.text.SimpleDateFormat, and invoke the resulting Date's getTime() method, which will get you the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,S Z");
Date date = df.parse("2012-09-01 13:44:21,222 GMT+2:00");
long time = date.getTime(); // milliseconds since epoch
```

For ISO 8601 Time zone:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,S Z");
Date date = df.parse("2012-09-01 13:44:21,222 +02");
```